# Direct address for 'you', does it need a comma or not?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> You, get out.

*You* is a direct address, so I'm asking the person to get out. Do I need to add the “,” between *you* and *get*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a terse command, it might be advisable to add the exclamation mark immediately after the pronoun (subject) or after the command:

1. You! Get out.
2. You. Get out!

Otherwise, I'd separate the pronoun from the verbal phrase with a comma and add the following for clarification.

3. You, get out [of here]!

Without the comma, the meaning changes, the end result appears fragmented.

4. You get out.

But “out” *of* where? The front door? The garage?

Comment: Yes, and there's a distinction between *you* being part of a form of address and a simple descriptive statement. (1) "Jane, get out of there." (2) "Jane gets out of there." In that example, the form of the verb also makes it clear which is which.